# UIButton Label being truncated

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder

My app supports French and English. In interface builder, I set label of UIButton to "Retry" and content hugging priority to 1000. The button is centered horizontally and it seems working fine in English UI. But in French, the button doesn't expand to accommodate French lable "Réessayer". It gets truncated. How do I set the contraints so that button would expand  to accommodate longer label?

[image]

[image]

One interesting outcome is, if I set inital label to French text instead of English, the label "Retry" is misaligned as you can see in the screeenshots.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to resolve this issue. I was setting button's label text using this statement : retryButton.titleLabel?.text = "Retry" which is not a proper way. Proper way is to use setTitle method provided by UIButton. I hope this helps others who are in the same situation as I do.